# Диалоговые окна. Как получить данные от дочернего окна?

Tags: java, javafx

Можно ли создать создать в JavaFx диалоговое окно что бы при вызове метода showDialog() он возвращал не которые парамеры,  как это происходит в Alert и он возвращает какую кнопку нажал пользователь.
И Как вообще получить данные от дочернего окна?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, вы можете создать второе окно, передав в него ссылку на основной контроллер:

```
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Resource.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        NewFolderController lc = (NewFolderController) loader.getController();
        lc.main = this;
        stage.setTitle("Create folder");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 200));
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.showAndWait();
```

Затем, в контроллере вашего второго окна, можно передавать данные в основной контроллер.

```
    @FXML
    VBox globParent;

    protected MainController main; // ссылка на основной контроллер
    main.newFileName = folderName.getText(); // передаем в основной контроллер какие-то данные
    globParent.getScene().getWindow().hide(); // закрываем текущее окно
```